# Error with getting ImageURI with Phonegap

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, image-gallery

I'm trying to get a photo from the user's camera or gallery using phonegap 3.0.0 (+angular)

For some reason, it works only for a photo taken captured by the camera

**This is my HTML:**

```
<button ng-click="getPhoto(0);">0</button><br>
<button ng-click="getPhoto(1);">1</button><br>
<button ng-click="getPhoto(2);">2</button><br>
<img ng-src="{{preview}}" />
```

Where the parameter of `getPhoto` is phonegap's `PictureSourceType`

```
Camera.PictureSourceType = {
    PHOTOLIBRARY : 0,
    CAMERA : 1,
    SAVEDPHOTOALBUM : 2
};
```

**And the code in the Javascript (Angular's control) is**

```
$scope.preview="";
$scope.getPhoto= function(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI)
                                {
                                    $scope.preview=imageURI;
                                },function(message) {
                                    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
                                },
                                {
                                    quality: 50,
                                    destinationType: 1,
                                    sourceType: source
                                });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Get photo from PHOTOLIBRARY

```
  navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI)                                {
                                $scope.preview=imageURI;
                        }, function(message) {
                                alert('Failed because: ' + message);
                        }, { quality: 50,destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});
```

Comment: this expression `navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY` is a long way to write `0`.   Why should it have any effect ?